# Keep geeting errors when I use razor views for the updated Hot Towel Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal, hottowel

I am using the upgraded version of Hot Towel template which has new versions of Durandal, Knockout, Breeze, etc. for a Single Page Application. This process works fine with the older version but not the newest.

This is the error I get:

> Unhandled exception at line 93, column 13 in [http://servername:50921/Scripts/durandal/viewEngine.js]
>
> 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined

I have changed the convention for the viewLocator in the main to use my ViewController.

```
    viewLocator.useConvention('viewmodels', '../../view');
    viewEngine.viewExtension = '/';
```

This use to work fine in the previous version of Hot Towel Template.

Please any ideas for the errors... will be grateful for any.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to open durandal/viewEngine.js, goto line 92, and put a breakpoint there and see what the value of whatever length is calling is.  Odds are you are referencing something that is not there, and it is trying to get the length of a null object.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the value of the length is 3 and couldn't help. Do you think because durandal folder is moved from App to Script folder could have an effect? You said it was referencing something that is not there.

Comment: Yep relative positioning is what you are using so you need to use the /../ to back up a folder from wherever the file you are calling it from is and then use that position to reference the other file.

Comment: Are you meaning to say that the extension of the file is a slash?  Shouldn't it be a .html ot something?